# Proving set equality (via proof of subsets)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm just starting a course on discrete mathematics, and I'm struggling a little to prove these two sets equal, as I am not entirely sure how the proof works. We are expected to use the proof that the two sets are subsets of each other, but I am not sure on how to do this in the following scenario:

$A = \{a^2 \mid a\in \mathbb{N}\}$

$B = \{(-b)^2 \mid b\in \mathbb{N}\}$

I know it's a bit of a basic question, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it algebraically:

$B = \{(-b)^2 \mid b\in \mathbb{N}\}$

$B = \{(-1 * b)^2 \mid b\in \mathbb{N}\}$

$B = \{(-1)^2 * b^2 \mid b\in \mathbb{N}\}$

$B = \{b^2 \mid b\in \mathbb{N}\}$

The rest is simply showing $a = b$, which is true $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: It's not as much showing that $a=b$ but more substituting $b$ with $a$.